# Unhandled Exception,passing two objects?

Tags: c++, class, exception, pointers, dynamic

Here are the 3 classes. Fraction/Rectangle/Box

```
class Fraction {
public:
    Fraction();
    Fraction(int);
    Fraction(int, int);
    ~Fraction();
    void setNum(int);
    void setDenom(int);
    int getNum(void) const;
    int getDenom(void) const;
    void print(void);
private:
   int num;
   int denom;
};

class Rectangle {
public:
    FinalRectangleRavuthL();
    ~FinalRectangleRavuthL();
    FinalRectangleRavuthL(Fraction&, Fraction&);
    void setLen(Fraction arg);
    void setWid(Fraction arg);
    Fraction getLen(void) const;
    Fraction getWid(void) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Rectangle&);
private:
Fraction *len; 
Fraction *wid;
};

class Box : public Rectangle {
public:
    Box();
    FinalBoxRavuthL(Rectangle& arg, Fraction& arg1);
    FinalBoxRavuthL(Fraction& arg);
    void print(void);
    void getBox(void);
    ~FinalBoxRavuthL();
private:
Fraction *height;
};
```

//Program

```
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Box.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Fraction::Fraction() {
    num = 0;
    denom = 1;
}
Fraction::Fraction(int n, int d) {
    num = n;
    denom = d;
}
Fraction& Fraction::operator=(const Fraction& arg) {
    num = arg.num;
    denom = arg.denom; 
    return *this;
}
Fraction::~Fraction() {
}

//Rectangle
Rectangle::Rectangle() {
    *len = FinalFractionRavuthL(2);
    *wid = FinalFractionRavuthL(1);
}
Rectangle::RectangleFraction& frac, Fraction& frac1) {
    cout << "First Fraction : ";
    frac.print();
    cout << "Second Fraction : ";
    frac1.print();
}

void Rectangle::setLen(Fraction arg) {
    len->setNum(arg.getNum());
    len->setDenom(arg.getDenom());
}
void Rectangle::setWid(Fraction arg) {
    wid->setNum(arg.getNum());
    wid->setDenom(arg.getDenom());
}
Fraction Rectangle::getLen(void) const {
    return Fraction(len->getNum(), len->getDenom());
}
Fraction Rectangle::getWid(void) const {
    return Fraction(wid->getNum(), wid->getDenom());
}
Rectangle::~Rectangle() {
    delete this->len;
    delete this->wid;
}

//Box
Box::Box() : height(new Fraction())
{
    height->setNum(0);
    height->setDenom(0);
}
Box::Box(Rectangle& arg, Fraction& arg1) : height(new Fraction())
{
    arg.getLen().print();
    arg.getWid().print();

    cout << arg1.getNum();
    cout << arg1.getDenom();
}
Box::Box(Fractio& arg) {
        height->setNum(arg.getNum());
    height->setDenom(arg.getDenom());
}
Box::~Box() {
    delete this->height;
}
```

The problem occurs when i call this in main

```
Fraction* fPtrA = new Fraction(4, 1);
Rectangle* rPtrA = new Rectangle(*fPtrA, *fPtrA);
Fraction* fPtrD = new Fraction(9, 1);

BoxRavuthL* boxPtrA = new Box(*rPtrA, *fPtrD); //PROBLEM
```

I put two fractions fPtrA into class Rectangle to make a rectangle
I create another fraction

then i pass the Rectangle and the fraction into Box

I know the problem has to do with the default constructor i made. Please help :)
I know i can use normal member data

Comment: Any reason to use `new` here?

Comment: How can Rectangle class have ~FinalRectangleRavuthL() as destructor?!

Comment: @PeterWood Although the rule of three is being violated this is not a duplicate of that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is the constructors for `Rectangle` are dereferencing the `Fraction` pointers before they been initialized resulting in undefined behavior.

```
// len and wid have not been initialized and point to random points in memory
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    *len = FinalFractionRavuthL(2);
    *wid = FinalFractionRavuthL(1);
}
```

You need to create a `Fraction` object for `len` and `wid`.

```
Rectangle::Rectangle()
    : len(new Fraction()), wid(new Fraction())
{
    *len = FinalFractionRavuthL(2);
    *wid = FinalFractionRavuthL(1);
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(Fraction& frac, Fraction& frac1)
    : len(new Fraction()), wid(new Fraction())
{
    // ....
}
```

Since it doesn't appear a pointer to  `Fraction` is really needed you can avoid the allocations with `new` by declaring the member variables with automatic storage duration. This will automatically initialize and destroy the objects without having to call `new` and `delete`

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    // ....
private:
    Fraction len;
    Fraction wid;
};
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    len = FinalFractionRavuthL(2);
    wid = FinalFractionRavuthL(1);
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(Fraction& frac, Fraction& frac1)
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention what the specific error is, one can only guess... But, since your `class Box ....` does not include a declaration for a constructor that takes two references (even though you seem to have supplied a definition for one outside the box), trying to call `new Box(x, y)` is going to fail because it can't find the right constructor to call. You should be getting errors on the definitions of the `Box` constructors that take arguments, as well, since they're not declared in the `class Box` body. There's a lot of other issues, too, but these are the ones specifically related to the line you have flagged.